# Firebug shows a class applied to my tag twice

Tags: css, firebug

When I'm trying to check my CSS applied to, I see a class is applied twice from a same class like the picture. what's wrong?
[image]

Comment: I don't see any mention of a class there. The style is applied to the `<body>` tag. I think it's saying that you loaded the same CSS file twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may have linked to General.css twice in your HTML code.

Comment: This is also described in the [Firebug FAQ](https://getfirebug.com/faq#What_does_the_number_after_the_file_name_inside_the_Style_side_panel_mean).