# Css rule Applied twice - Overrides !important

Tags: html, css

So I have these two classes, and they are in separate css file

```
.conditional { background-color: #ffd0d0 !important; }

 span.fieldz { background-color: #FFFF00; height: auto !important; width: auto !important; }
```

What happens is that the background color for `.conditional` is not being applied even thought it has the `!important` declaration. The HTML looks correct

```
<span class='conditional' contenteditable='true'>
   <span class='fieldsz' contenteditable='false'>[Usesles Text]</span>
</span>
```

When I inspect the css I see the rule being applied twice for each class. 
[image]

[image]

And when I uncheck the fieldz class (both of them) only then is the background with the `!important` applied. How is this overriding the the `!important` declaration? I also have checked to see if I am referencing the `.css` twice as suggested [here in this SO post where the class is applied twice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202466/firebug-shows-a-class-applied-to-my-tag-twice) But I am only referencing each of the `.css` file once.

Comment: Do your css rules appear twice in the css file?  Can you provide a reproduction?  If not, everyone will be guessing.

Comment: In the image of the inspector, the rule you want is being applied correctly. Your question is confusing.

Comment: I think firebug gives you a line number, so you can see if the rule applied 2 times is on different lines or not. Also, they are spans, the fieldz would show up overlapping the conditional. If you can recreate this on http://jsfiddle.net it would help

Comment: @recursive It is going to be hard to reproduce this I am also not sure what is causing the css rule to be applied twice, which is why I reference the SO talking about what can cuase it

Comment: There are three things I know that can cause this.  Multiple css files, multiple css rule declarations in the same css file, and dynamically created css rules by javascript.  If you think it's hard to reproduce, it's even harder to provide answers without a reproduction.

Comment: @recursive yeah I was hoping that someone encounter this before. But the dynamic created css is something I am going to look deeper into.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the double entries in the inspector come from, but the behaviour of the colours is normal.
If you apply `!important` to a property on an element, it does not override the same property on *another* element.
So, the `.conditional` span is pink, and the `.fieldz` span is yellow, and that's what you see. Since the `.fieldz` is inside the `.conditional`, it gets drawn on top of it.

[image]